# How to create a complex aggregate function in sqlite

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sql-date-functions, sql-max

Suppose I have the following table where there are two sets of observation dates (`2015-01-01`, `2016-01-01`) in the first column. For each observation date, there are associated `item_date` and `item_value`.

| observation_date | item_date | item_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2015-01-01 | 2012-12-31 | 0 |
| 2015-01-01 | 2013-03-31 | 1 |
| 2015-01-01 | 2013-06-30 | 2 |
| 2015-01-01 | 2013-09-30 | 3 |
| 2015-01-01 | 2013-12-31 | 4 |
| 2015-01-01 | 2014-03-31 | 5 |
| 2015-01-01 | 2014-06-30 | 6 |
| 2015-01-01 | 2014-09-30 | 7 |
| 2016-01-01 | 2013-09-30 | 8 |
| 2016-01-01 | 2013-12-31 | 9 |
| 2016-01-01 | 2014-03-31 | 10 |
| 2016-01-01 | 2014-06-30 | 11 |
| 2016-01-01 | 2014-09-30 | 12 |
| 2016-01-01 | 2014-12-31 | 13 |
| 2016-01-01 | 2015-03-31 | 14 |
| 2016-01-01 | 2015-06-30 | 15 |
| 2016-01-01 | 2015-09-30 | 16 |

If I were to group by `observation_date` and get `max(item_date)`, I would get the following result.

| observation_date | item_date | item_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2015-01-01 | 2014-09-30 | 7 |
| 2016-01-01 | 2015-09-30 | 16 |

Now instead of the `max` aggregate function, I'd like to create my own function. My goal is as follows:
For each observation date, I would like to return the row where the `item_date` is `n` years before the `max(item_date)`. For example, if `n=1`, I would get the rows where the `item_date` is 1 year ago from the `max(item_date)`.

| observation_date | item_date | item_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2015-01-01 | 2013-09-30 | 3 |
| 2016-01-01 | 2014-09-30 | 12 |

Note that I simply do not want just the dates, but the whole row. I've been looking at sqlite's [`create_aggregate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.create_aggregate) functionality but I don't know how to return the full row. Any ideas how I can do this?

If there are more efficient ways to achieve this, please let me know.

Comment: Are you certain that there is always a row with a date equal to max date - 1 year for each observation_date?

Comment: If you are using `n=1` would an `item_date` 11 months before not show? And if I understand correctly, you want only 1 record, correct?

Comment: @RuiCosta Why would `n=1` show a date 11 months ago instead of 12? And yes, I want only 1 record

Comment: @forpas Yes, if there are enough rows preceding the date, there will always be date equal to max date - 1 year and so on. `item_date` is a sequence of continuous quarterly end dates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a correlated subquery that returns for each `observation_date` the max date minus `?` years:

```
sql = """
SELECT t1.*
FROM tablename t1
WHERE t1.item_date = (
  SELECT DATE(MAX(t2.item_date), '-' || ? || ' year') 
  FROM tablename t2 
  WHERE t2.observation_date = t1.observation_date
);
"""
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql, ("1",))
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=efffecbf368bcb50615a37744b220841).

Comment: I did not know about correlated subquery and this solves the problem. Thanks!